# Why do some people get angry at questions?

Tags: discussion

I am a new user here.

I do not know why some people got angry with me because of some mistakes in my questions. If I am a professional in the English language, why would I even ask? Isn't it to be expected that I would make mistakes?

Comment: I just had a quick look at your posts, of which there are but two, and I am not seeing the anger. In fact on one of your posts you got excellent comments by a linguistics professor. Can you please point to the comments you deemed angry?

Comment: @RegDwigнt [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173119/) looks _not very welcoming_ to me. "**Are** there any English words formed from only the letters **A, R,** and **E** (in that order, with no repeated letters)?" It's OK for me, I speak English but understand that some people have difficulties. Some indication of ripping the piss might be appropriate, a smiley perhaps.

Comment: @Frank: That was my comment, so I suppose I'd better attempt to justify it. So far as I was concerned, I was simply facetiously amplifying the preceding comment (which pointed out that OP had first presented examples, then asked whether any such examples existed). I wasn't *angry*, and I didn't intend to be negative to the OP himself. I just thought (and still do) that the question as originally framed was unclear and/or pointless.

Comment: @Frank when i asked,they told me that the pronounce of 't' is /t/
when i heard it in the examples,i couldn't hear it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Angry - I didn't see angry either but I did see _not very welcoming_ which could be taken for angry quite easily I think. There are quite a number of comments to questions that are ambiguously phrased that are not asking directly for more information or suggesting improvement and that I can imagine could come across as appearing angry. Unless it's in response to a regular user on the site, witty or sharp comments could be understood as angry, rude or aloof.

Comment: @Frank that is a fair point in general, but in this particular case it falls flat, as the OP has already specified he meant an entirely different comment on an entirely different question. Which is why we should always wait for clarification *by the OP*. Everything else is speculation about a loaded question. If you specifically set out to look for blue cars, then you will start seeing them everywhere. We should really let FumbleFingers off the hook here.

Answer (score 8):

**A good question gets good answers.**

I will offer my opinion as to why you have not gotten the answers you wished for (though I would not qualify the responses as *angry* at all.)

The site expressly recommends that you explain the **problem you're having** in your question.(*"Great subjective questions invite sharing experiences over opinions."*)

In [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172783/whats-the-correct-pronunciation-of-g-and-t-here) question, it was not clear in your post that "when [you] listened to a T character in English courses as in "doubt you", "about you" and "I don't know", a T character was not pronounced" (a comment you made more than two hours after your question was entered). Had you done this, it would have allowed users to zero in on the problem you experienced instead of giving you *answers you were not actually seeking.*

This can be frustrating not only to the person asking the question (who might wonder why their question isn't being addressed straightforwardly), but also  to the user who has to *try to guess* what it is you're actually asking in order to answer you directly.

The same principle applies to this question: "Are there any English words where we place the tip of the tongue between teeth? For example: *other* and *that*"

The fact that you gave two such words as examples makes your question confusing. You obviously know that there are such words. Which leaves the reader to wonder *"what, exactly, is he asking?"* These types of questions are discouraged here, and the question was placed on hold for the following reason: **put on hold as unclear what you're asking** (list-type questions - a list of words with *th* in them - are also discouraged here.)

There is a learning curve for new users of any site. One thing a good user will learn is how to ask a *good question*. Good questions don't encourage people to *guess* at what, exactly, the user is asking. Good questions are clear about it.

Try to be more specific, and share your problems, in your next question. See if that makes a difference in the reception and the answers you get.